# How to skip this extra and unnecessary row in php do while and mysql fetch assoc?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking through various sites on how to skip one extra row generated by `mysql fetch assoc` and php `do while`, but could not find this solution. I am generating html table from database. From the following code I am getting one extra empty row. I have three data on my database table. Here this code is generating five rows while I expect four.

My complete code is as under:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from $table where Year='2013'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
?>
<table><tr>
<th>Name</Name>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
<td><?php  $ndt = strtotime($row['date']); echo date('d-M-Y', $ndt); ?></td>
 <?php } while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: mysql_* function are deprecated... switch to mysqli or pdo

Comment: @Orangepill Do you have any suggestion how I could solve this problem with mysql_*?

Comment: With do while loop, it is expected to run 1 extra time.i mean on the first cycle. switch to for or while loop

Comment: The easiest solution would be to switch over to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)... it has a very similar api to mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switch to a while loop .

```
<?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
<td><?php  $ndt = strtotime($row['date']); echo date('d-M-Y', $ndt); ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

The first time through your do/while loop $row is not populated,  thus you where getting an empty row.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use while loop?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from $table where Year='2013'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
?>
<table><tr>
<th>Name</Name>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
<td><?php  $ndt = strtotime($row['date']); echo date('d-M-Y', $ndt); ?></td>
 <?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code below :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
<?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
        <td><?php  $ndt = strtotime($row['date']); echo date('d-M-Y', $ndt); ?></td>
<?php } ; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```